# storing several ID's from another table in one column?

Tags: php, mysql

Apologies if this is really stupid but I don't have any experience in php and mysql to know how things should be done. I have a customer table in a mysql db and a group table:

customers - ID name email phone group
groups - ID name description

So I need to assign groups to customers if necessary, this can be more than one group to each customer. So e.g. customer 1 is in group 4,5,6

What way should I assign groups in the group column of the customer table. Should I just add the group ID's separated by commas, then just use explode when I need to get the individual ID's out?

Maybe this isn't the right approach at all, could someone enlighten me please. I would appreciate knowing the right way to do this, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Do not store multiple IDs in one column. This is a denormalization that will make it much harder to query and change your data, as well as hurting performance.

Instead, create a separate `CustomerGroup` table (with `CustomerID` and `GroupID` columns), and have one row per Customer/Group relationship.

Comment: thanks, I think I already knew in some way this would make queries difficult but I was looking for the easiest (laziest) way I could think of.

Comment: Easiest way to write it now, or maintain it later? I have seen this mistake many times (putting comma delimited values in a SQL field) and never once has it failed to produce a huge problem down the line.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I just add the group ID's separated by commas, then just use explode when I need to get the individual ID's out?

No! If you do that then you won't quickly be able to (for example) query for which users there are in a specific group.

Instead use a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) with two columns, each of which has a foriegn key constraint to the corresponding table.

```
group_id  customer_id
4         1
5         1
6         1
```

Comment: thanks for the link, explains it well. I'm a bit confused though, e.g. when creating such a table I would use REFERENCES customer (ID), what happens if I try to enter a customer ID into that join table that doesn't exist, will I get an error?

Comment: @mao: Yes, you will get an error if you try to add a value that doesn't exist in the referenced table. The row won't be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of tables to show how you should implement this :

Table 1  CONSUMERS:

```
id name email 
1  john john@something.com
2  ray  ray@something.com
```

Table 2 GROUPS :

```
id group_name   description
1  music        good music group
2  programming  programmers
```

Table 3  CONSUMERS_GROUPS

```
consumer_id  group_id
1              1
1              2
2              1
```

Now the table 3 is listing consumers ids which belong to which group id.

This type of relationship is called ***one to many*** relation where, one consumer can have many groups. Reverse might also be true where one group can have many consumers. In that case relationship is called ***many to many***